# What is this shooting game that looks like Ukraine?

Tags: game-identification

Please, help me identify [this game](https://cloud.video.taobao.com/play/u/1746864514/p/1/e/6/t/1/50026792639.mp4).

To me it looks like a mixture of STALKER, GTA and Call of Duty. It has motorcycles and sniper shooting while racing, while the location seems to be somewhere in ex-USSR.

Snapshots from the video:

[image: top down view of a building being bombed]

[image: character walking by bombed out car]

I found the video on TaoBao in a video card advertisement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The game is called [PlayerUnknown's Battlegrounds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PlayerUnknown%27s_Battlegrounds) (PUBG).

It looks like Ukraine because the game really drew some inspiration from the Chernobyl Exclusion Zone (possibly through S.T.A.L.K.E.R.). For example, the game features an [abandoned swimming pool](https://www.reddit.com/r/PUBATTLEGROUNDS/comments/62ppbu/look_familiar_to_anyone/) which looks exactly like [Azure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azure_Swimming_Pool) (*Lazurnyi*) swimming pool in Prypiat, Ukraine.